# NoMethodError while rendering a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `welcome.html.erb` page with `welcome_controller`. On this page I try to render a partial which belongs to `Screen` model, but it returns `NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`. Here's the code:

**`welcome.html.erb`**:

```
<%= render 'screens/all` %>
```

**`_all.html.erb`**:

```
<%= @screens.each do |screen| %>
    <%= link_to screen do %>
        <img src="">
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**`screens_controller.rb`**:

```
def all
    @screens = Screen.all.order('created_at ASC')
end
```

Comment: 'screens/all` - is it a typo?(i mean ending quote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are doing wrong.

```
def all
    @screens = Screen.all.order('created_at ASC')
end
```

That method you have in `screens_controller.rb`

You need to write the instance inside the welcome method at `welcome_controller.rb`, That way it will not give error to you.

That way you can access the partial and one more thing pass the variable in locals with partial and use that instead of the actual instance.

```
<%= render :partial =>'screens/all`, :locals => {:screens => @screens} %>
```

Comment: Also, in the partial `@screens` would become `screens` then

Comment: @Bharat thank you! so in `welcome_controller.rb` I should write the same method as in `screens_controller`, do I understand right?

Comment: You are right. All the instance which you need on the page that you have to write.

Answer (score 1):

The instance variable you're using (`@screens`) should be coming from whatever controller action renders `welcome.html.erb`. You should then pass it explicitly as a local (like Bharat shows in his answer).

Answer (score 0):

you Forgot to pass the variable

Try using

```
<%= render 'screens/all',:screens => @screens %>
```